# Aligning a UILabel with the center of UISlider thumb image in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uislider

I have a UILabel that displays the value of a UISlider.

How can I allign the UILabel with the center of the UISlider thumb image in Swift, so that the slider's value is always displayed in the center of the thumb image?

Comment: have you managed to solve this problem? I'm stuck at this point, too.

Comment: Do you want the readout of the slider’s current value to appear inside the slider thumb (i.e. on the circle) ? Should it move as the slider moves ? In which case the UILabel would appear only when users take their finger off the slider. Is that OK ?